# How to write a lookahead regex that checks for two or more characters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I have strings like these:

```
str = "Word word ReplaceThis DONT word word"
```

I only want to replace `ReplaceThis` **only if it's not followed by two or more upper case letters** (in this example `DONT`).

How can I write a lookahead in my regex to handle that? Here is what I've tried:

```
str.sub!(/\bReplaceThis\b/i, "NewWord"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

user3188544, this might be the simple answer you are looking for:

```
replace = str.gsub(/ReplaceThis(?!\s?[A-Z]{2})/, 'NewWord')
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a lookahead or behind you can use a capture group as below:

```
another_str = "Please ReplaceThis now"  
another_str.gsub(/(ReplaceThis) (?=[A-za-z][^A-Z]{1,})/, 'NewWord \2')
#=> "Please NewWord now"

str = "Word word ReplaceThis DONT word word"
str.gsub(/(ReplaceThis) (?=[A-za-z][^A-Z]{1,})/, 'NewWord \2')
#=> "Word word ReplaceThis DONT word word"
```

Capture Group combined with Positive lookahead solution:

```
str = "Word word ReplaceThis DONT word word"
str.gsub(/(ReplaceThis) (?=[A-za-z][^A-Z]{1,})/, 'NewWord \2')
#=> "Word word ReplaceThis DONT word word"

another_str = "Please ReplaceThis now" 
another_str.gsub(/(ReplaceThis) (?=[A-za-z][^A-Z]{1,})/, 'NewWord \2')
#=> "Please NewWord now"
```

Comment: That's not the desired result -- it should not replace the word if `DONT` exists.

Answer (score 0):

```
result = re.sub(r"(?s)\bReplaceThis\b\s+(?![A-Z]{2,})", "newword", subject)
```

Answer (score 0):

This pattern uses a positive lookahead:

```
(ReplaceThis)(?=\s[a-z]{2}+)
```

**Code:**

```
replace = searchText.gsub(/(ReplaceThis)(?=\s[a-z]{2}+)/x, "NewWord")
```

**Example:**

http://regex101.com/r/lX8mF8